# Change multiple images/elements on hover for overlayed images HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I created a notecard image where i overlayed multiple images on top of it. These are elements of the notecard. I want it so that when I hover over the notecard, I can completely change the contents on the notecard image (overlaying new things onto the notecard).

So right now, I have this right now:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <a href="#games">
        <img id "image_a" a" src="images/card_normal.png" onmouseover "this.src rc 'images/hover/card_hover.png';" ;" onmouseout "this.src rc 'images/card_normal.png';" ;" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
        <img id "image_b" b" src="images/category_icons/icon_games.png" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 40px;"/>
        <img id "image_c" c" src="images/category_titles/title_games.png" style="position: absolute; top: 160px; left: 40px;"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Where the notecard changes into a "hovered" version, but I am unable to change anything else. I want it so that whenever the mouse pointer is in the notecard (including if its on other elements inside the notecard), the contents change. I want to completely scrap the contents of it (so the title and icon) and change it so I can add text and overlay new images.

How can I do this in JS/HTML/etc?

Comment: The JavaScript event you are looking for is `onmouseover`.  You can read about it at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp).

Comment: That only helps me change one image to another. I need to change multiple elements and add/subtract elements.

Comment: Probably a combination of css and js, depending on how complex you want to go. A small, random example of powerful, yet easy, things that can be done with jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/9eLC6/

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to Learner's answer, here is an example of the idea you are describing:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    width: 304px;
    height: 304px;
    background-color: black;
}
.inner {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
}
.outer:hover .inner {
    display: block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisP/a37Uv/)

Answer (score 1):

If the two versions (hover/non-hover) are significantly different (and you want a no-js solution), you could have two divs, one set to hide, one set to show. Then on-hover, you change their visibility. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidg707/zPs6h/).

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="no-hover">
    stuff you want to show when the user is just looking
  </div>
  <div class="on-hover">
    stuff you want to show when the user hovers
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.no-hover {
  display: block;
}
.on-hover {
  display: none;
}
.card:hover > .on-hover {
  display: block;
}
.card:hover > .no-hover {
  display: none;
}
```

It's extra HTML elements, but might be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieve something like this:
http://spoonfedproject.com/wp-content/uploads/demo/jquery-slide-hover/index.htm

Here's your solution:
http://www.robertkuzma.com/2011/01/jquery-animated-swap-div-content-on-hover-effect/

Comment: Think of a piece of paper (which is an image). On that piece of paper there are 2 images overlayed on top. When the mouse is hovered over it, it changes so the contents of that paper are now 4 images overlayed on top and a description on the piece of paper (or overlayed on top of the paper image) .How do I do this?

Comment: Sorry still not getting it. Any live example or prototype available?